# API PHP Partner WSDL REQUIRED_FIELDS_MISSING

Tags: api, soap-api, opportunity, php

I am having an issue with the Partner WSDL. When attempting to create a new opportunity over the API I am getting a return stating that required fields are missing. These fields are correctly being set prior to the message being sent. IN addition I have looked at the user logs and there are no errors with Validation rules etc... Below are samples of the object sent and the return.

Thanks for any help in advance!

**Part of the object sent**

```
object(SObject)#5 (2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(11) "Opportunity"
  ["fields"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (48) {
    ["RecordTypeId"]=>
    string(18) "xxxxx"
    ["OwnerId"]=>
    string(18) "xxxxx"
    ["AccountId"]=>
    string(18) "xxxxx"
    ["CloseDate"]=>
    string(25) "2014-03-18T00:00:00-04:00"
    ["StageName"]=>
    string(25) "Closed"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(16) "test - delete me"
    }
}
```

**Return message from API**

```
   object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
    ["errors"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#18 (3) {
        ["fields"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(4) "Name"
          [1]=>
          string(9) "StageName"
          [2]=>
          string(9) "CloseDate"
        }
        ["message"]=>
        string(57) "Required fields are missing: [Name, StageName, CloseDate]"
        ["statusCode"]=>
        string(22) "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING"
      }
    }
    ["id"]=>
    NULL
    ["success"]=>
    bool(false)
    }
```

**Edit to add code**

```
//create new opp fields
$newOpportunityFields = new StdClass();

//set fields
$newOpportunityFields->Name = 'test - delete me';
$newOpportunityFields->StageName = 'Fully Executed Contract Received';
$newOpportunityFields->CloseDate = date('c', strtotime( $currentOpportunity->CloseDate));


//turn stdclass into array for the fields array
$newFields = json_decode(json_encode($newOpportunity), true);

//create Soap object for creation
$sObject = new SObject();
$sObject->fields = $newFields;
$sObject->type = 'Opportunity';

//send
$return  = $connection->create($sObject);
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: what happens if you try to create the opportunity via the GUI? You might be missing an authorization or there might be another process (trigger, workflow) blanking out the fields again..

Comment: There is a workflow, however all required fields are entered. If i use the Gui to enter the Opportunity it works immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see here is that `create()` takes an array, rather than a single record. I'm also not sure why you're doing the stdclass -> JSON -> array transformation - just create the array directly. This code works for me:

```
$sObject = new SObject();
$sObject->fields = array(
    'Name' => 'test - delete me',
    'StageName' => 'Prospecting',
    'CloseDate' => '2014-12-31',
);
$sObject->type = 'Opportunity';

$response = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));
```

Comment: Creating the array directly into the SObject does not work either. I get the same message. Is there a way on the Salesforce side to see the message as it comes in and find the point of failure?

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code?

Comment: After reviewing your code I found the issue. I was passing the $sObject directly into the create method, instead of passing an array containing the $sObject. I incorrectly assumed that you could pass a single sObject into the method without it being inside of an array Thanks for your help!

Comment: Now you have to change your username from h8a to <3a :-)